# roscore doesn't start normally anymore?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

since a week or so, starting roscore doesn't work normally om my machine.
The program hangs most of the time, there is nothing more than the command I entered.
It only  starts if I Ctrl-C the hanging roscore, then it suddenly starts. Very strange.

If I, e.g., start rviz it has the same behaviour (often), it only really starts when I ctrl-C the hanging program.

There were no ros-updates in the last month I think.
I am running ubuntu 14.04 and indigo, all standard.

What can we wrong here?  Thanks in advance,

Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223800/roscore-doesn%27t-start-normally-anymore?/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It only starts if I Ctrl-C the hanging roscore, then it suddenly starts.

It normally takes care of this by itself, but sometimes ROS needs a little help: run a `rosclean check` and see if it also hangs (or takes a very long time to complete). That is the program that is run first by `roscore`: it keeps tabs on the nr of log files (and their total size). On a regular HDD (so not an SSD), that can take quite some time.

If `rosclean check` also 'hangs', you can either run `rosclean purge`, or manually `rm ~/.ros/log/*.log`. In both cases make sure you have nothing there you'd like to keep.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2016-01-11**:
**rosclean check** check returns immediately, there was 109MB logging.
After **rosclean purge** nothing is changed, so that isn't the problem...
Any other possibility?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-11**:
Make sure you don't have any incorrect info in your `/etc/hosts`, or a wrong `ROS_IP` / `ROS_HOSTNAME` in your `.bashrc`. Especially on university / corporate networks (where addressing may change without notice) that sometimes leads to strange (and hard to diagnose) issues.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thanks, that was it!  It was some mixup between an extra network interface (to connect to our robots) and the university-linux-network-setup.

**Comment by [robtos](https://answers.ros.org/users/123836/robtos/) on 2023-07-02**:
/etc/hosts /etc/nss  and  /etc/nsswitch.conf  check . ping 127.0.0.1 slowly